# localization and non localization for different targets

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am having an iOS application with localization enabled for few languages.

Now I want to make another application with same codebase as a different target , But I don't need localization for new target how can I achieve this?

Comment: you can make a bypass method for localization

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented using a helper function in my strings extension.

```
extension String{
 var localized: String {
        #if TARGET_A
        return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
        #elif
         return self
      #endif
    }
}
```

- As my localisation depends on the language selected in settings it will work.